# href to a different part on the same page not working in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've made some href's that refer to a specific part of the page in my header.
I'm using handlebars and the the href is in the header template and the destination is in another template here is a snippet of my code:

in header.html:

```
<li><a href="#PLATEAU"> PLATEAU </a> </li>
```

in shop_page.html:

```
<h2> <span id="PLATEAU">PLATEAU</span></h2>
```

expected result:
When I click on the hyperlink in my header I expect to go the the span with the destination id.

Actual result:
I see that my path changes to #PLATEAU but I don't jump to the correct part of the page.

additional info:
using iron-router, bootstrap-3 packages. chrome. macbook pro. meteor version 0.7.1.2

Any help appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Everything looks okay but I suspect it actually has more to do with the CSS on the page. Commonly, depending on how you're positioning things on your page, your H tags CAN have false crazy heights. The top of the element very well could be at the top of your page but the text for it appears in the right place. Try inspecting the element to make sure that everything is in the right place and has the right height.

Comment: If you remove the Iron Router package, does the behavior change?

Comment: The h tag is in place.

Comment: Removing iron router isn't an option since my app won't render without it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [Iron Router docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#query-strings-and-hash-segments), Query Strings and Hashes aren't used to route. If you need routing you could use `actualPath/plateau` instead of `actualPath#Plateau` and use iron router to render your new content.

But if you want to use de hashs here's what maybe you can do. I did this for a tab system.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentTab',function(page){
    return Session.get('activeTab') == page;
});
```

In HTML:

```
{{#if currentTab 'PLATEAU'}}
    {{> PLATEAU}}
{{/if}}

<template name="PLATEAU">
<h2> <span id="PLATEAU">PLATEAU</span></h2>
</template>
```

In your js again

```
Template.yourTemplate.events({
    'click .tabChange': function(e, t) {
        Session.set('activeTab', window.location.hash);
    }
});
```

I no longer use this so this is an untested code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166374/create-a-reusable-template-for-tabs-in-meteor?answertab=active#tab-top) maybe help you too.
Highly recommend to use `path/:activeTab` for better code.

Comment: I dont want to render a new page. I want to navigate to a different part of my current page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming shop-page.html is called 'shop-page' in your router.js file, you can do the following:

```
# Create link to anchor
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'shop-page' hash='plateau'}}">PLATEAU</a></li>

# Set anchor
<h2><span id="plateau">PLATEAU</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this.
Links dont by default work in Metoer (I read somewhere that it has to do with blaze), #linking though should work, but link to a new page need to be routed

Answer (score 0):

*This was tested on Meteor 1.2.1 (with iron router 1.0.12) -- should work with later versions as well (older versions may need some one or two changes in supplied code)*

First of all, it is better to change the markup to

```html
<li><a href="{{pathFor route='yourRouteName' hash='PLATEAU'}}">PLATEAU</a></li>
```

Now .. you need a workaround for this persistent [issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/373), this is the one I use :

```js
Router.onAfterAction(function() {
  var hash = this.getParams().hash;
  Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
    if (hash && $("#"+hash).length) {
      // go to element
      Tracker.nonreactive(function() {
        window.location.hash = "";
        window.location.hash = "#"+hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

There is some other ideas for the part after `// go to element` like :

```js
  var scrollTop = $("#" + self.params.hash).offset().top;
  $("html,body").scrollTop(scrollTop);
```

or (to have an animation) :

```js
  var scrollTop = $("#" + self.params.hash).offset().top;
  $("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTop
  });
}
```

References (related iron router issues on github) :

- [Issue 248](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/248) - [Issue 373](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/373) - [Issue 1017](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1017) - [Issue 1171](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1171)